# Email template - Background image with text overlay at exact location

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm building a HTML-mail where should be an image with a number on top of it.
So far I have added the image as a td-background with a nested table to position the text. It looks good in most email clients, except… Outlook.
Outlook renders the text
- to the right (Outlook 2003)
- too high (Outlook 2007 and up)

Example: 
[image: https://s31.postimg.org/6rhbz8diz/Schermafbeelding_2016_07_28_om_19_58_07.png]

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td background="https://s31.postimg.org/57s9ntmij/basket_3.png" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="35" height="30" valign="top" style="font-size: 0;">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:35px;height:30px;">
                <v:fill type="frame" src="https://e.kaartje2go.nl/public/Kaartje2go/8553f93ebcf5d20eb1da4a3b8abeaaba/basket_3.png" color="#ffffff" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="30" style="line-height:20px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20"></td>
                            <td height="15" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;font-weight:700; line-height:20px;" >
                                2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The HTML can be found here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXpKRQ?editors=1000

I have tried different height’s and line-height’s, but nothing seems to help.
Can somebody please help me to fix the position of the text?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Some tags and css will not work in email tamplate. Please refer this solution
https://freshmail.com/developers/best-practices-for-email-coding/

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this playing around (some more) with the line-height values.

There where multiple line-heights defined, in the table itself and his parent table. I removed the parent's line-height and changed the value of the td line-height and width to fix alignment in the Gmail app.

This is the final solution:

```html
<table width="35" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td background="https://s31.postimg.org/57s9ntmij/basket_3.png" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="35" height="30" valign="top" style="font-size: 0;">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:35px;height:30px;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://s31.postimg.org/57s9ntmij/basket_3.png" color="#ffffff" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
               <![endif]-->
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="35">
        <tr>
          <td width="14"></td>
          <td width="21" height="20" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;font-weight:700; line-height:14px;">
            2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:rect>
         <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It renders good in most email clients (except Outlook 120 DPI..)

Comment: Adding mso-line-height-rule: exactly; to your style will help keep Outlook (esp. 2013) from adding extra height to your cells. Outlook 2013 is also funny about valign (although it defaults to top rather than middle) but it will respect vertical-align in style. I often use both to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is not working, because Outlook seems to be weird when align and vagign is used.

You aligned your secound td in the Center of the rest of the space. The rest of the width is 15px. Try adding the width to your second table and align your text with the text-align:center; .

If this doesn't work, you could just set the width of the second td to 0 and add a third td with the width of 15. Then you play around with the width's of the first and third td to get the text where it belongs.

Also for the height you could try adding a

```
<td .. >
   <span style="line-height: 5px;"><br></span><br>2
</td>
```

This is a bit quick and dirty, but maybe gets the job done. this way you could set the height of the td to 12px and remove all the lineheight.

Also you could try to add padding to the table or the td to make the height right.

I'm sorry I don't have a exact answer, but I only have access to a Outlook2010 Client. But maybe something of this works, or at least you got some inspiration.